# Get a single document by foreign key in using RxJs and AngularFirestore

Tags: rxjs, angularfire2

I've written a query that looks like this:

```
getPaymentByBookingId(id: string): Observable<Payment> {
    return this.afs.collection<Payment>('payments', ref => ref.where('bookingId', '==', id).limit(1))
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
            flatMap(array => from(array)),
            first()
        );
}
```

Where a `Payment` object has a unique reference to a `Booking` id. I want to find the Payment for a given ID.

This seems like quite a convoluted way to right this query.

Is there a simpler way to do this - including if there is a code smell here that makes this hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit simpler is:

```
getPaymentByBookingId(id: string): Observable<Payment> {
    return this.afs.collection<Payment>('payments', ref => ref.where('bookingId', '==', id).limit(1))
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(array => array[0]),
        );
}
```

this will returned `undefined` if the payment is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it solely using Javascript native array API [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and it will save you a couple lines of code:

```
getPaymentByBookingId(id: string): Observable<Payment> {
    return this.afs.collection<Payment>('payments')
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(allPayments=>allPayments.find(payment=>payment.bookingId === id))
        );
}
```

Or you can use the [`.first()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html) operator and supply its first-met condition:

```
getPaymentByBookingId(id: string): Observable<Payment> {
    return this.afs.collection<Payment>('payments')
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
            flatMap(array => from(array)),
            first(eachPayment => eachPayment.bookingId === id)
        );
}
```

Note that there is a fundamental difference in how the filtering works behind the scene. I personally prefer the Javascript's native function, as I feel it's kinda redundant to transform the observable using `from(array)` just so that it is emitting the array sequence one by one.

Also note that by doing `ref => ref.where('bookingId', '==', id)`, you filtering actually happens at query level (aka not at client side). If you are confident that the number of `payments` retrieved won't be big, then it's fine to let the client side do the filtering; else its always better to offload the processing part to the server.

Comment: Does this not move the query from (potentially) the firebase server to the JS client? meaning it will need to download all payments in order to find the correct one?

Comment: @MarkHughes yes you are right. I guess I will edit and make it clearer.

Comment: I feel like your answer is fundamentally problematic - it really wouldn't be suitable to pull in the entire collection and then filter it.