# Simplest way to get a single document with angularfire2

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to have a basic form so that I can update data.
I can query a full collection (and optionally could maybe filter on client-side the data I need, event if it didn't yet work for me).

I can query a single doc when I know the id.
But I'd like to query a collection with business criteria and be able to add it in my view (and of course get a way to update data when updated by the form.)

Actually my question seems to be really close to [Get a single document by foreign key in using RxJs and AngularFirestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834511/get-a-single-document-by-foreign-key-in-using-rxjs-and-angularfirestore)
But :

- getting all data and filter it after seems to me a bad solution
- I tried, but I'm not sure to understand the meaning (the type) of allPayments and payment (for this I guess it's a business class if so, okay) in this given example :

  ```
  getPaymentByBookingId(id: string): Observable<Payment> {
   return this.afs.collection<Payment>('payments')
       .valueChanges()
       .pipe(
      map(allPayments=>allPayments.find(payment=>payment.bookingId === id))
     );
   }
  ```

I just got an

```
    Cannot read property '<my_attribute' of undefined
```

which suppose the get is returning a null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggested, filtering on the client side is not the ideal way to do this. You need to query the collection on `bookingId` and then `limit()` this to one result.

This will still return an array with one item (`limit(1)`), but you can flatten the result with `flatMap()` to get a single `Payment`:

```
getPaymentByBookingId(id: string): Observable<Payment> {
    return this.afs
        .collection<Payment>('payments', ref => ref.where('bookingId', '==', id).limit(1))
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
            flatMap(payments => payments)
        );
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Thanks. The next step will for me to find how to get an async version of this, because I get the value of firestore when loading the component, changes after not shown until I reload.